# PXE network installations / Live Sessions

Tags: networking, installation, pxe-boot

I was wondering is it possible to "link" more than one PXE server together?
i.e. have 2 seperate physical PXE servers both configured in there own ways...
but having machine A to be the primary (ip address configured in dhcp) but then having an menu option to boot / load the menu (that type of thing) of the second PXE server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is called "chaining", and whether or not it's supported depends on what your PXE bootloader supports.  I don't know any off the top of my head that will do it, but it's technically possible.  I'd be looking for a more conventional way to do whatever it is that you want to do, though -- PXE chaining would be awfully fragile.